# How to review git pull requests (hosted on bitbucket) in intelliJ?

Tags: bitbucket, pull-request, intellij-13, github-codereviews

How can I review the git pull requests in intelliJ Idea (2018.3) and check the compile time, test run impact and other IDE features before approving or rejecting?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Code Review for Bitbucket](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13538-code-review-for-bitbucket/) plugin.